# Storm transformation which does REST call (async, Future, Netty)

Tags: asynchronous, netty, apache-storm

Let's assume that Storm receives a stream of 1000's of tweets per second and that somewhere in the process, it needs to classify them as spam or not. I have a cluster of e.g. 20 machines that provide the "classification" microservice through a REST API and they can give max throughput of 10k tweets per second and their latency is 3 seconds. This means that at worst case, I might have 30k tweets on the fly and that's ok. I guess that to consume this service from Storm, an implementation will be something like this:

```
public static class RestBolt implements IRichBolt {
    ...
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        String classes = (new Post('http://my.classifier.com', data = tuple.getString(0)));
        _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(classes));
        _collector.ack(tuple);
    }
    ...
}

topologyBuilder.setBolt("rest-bolt", new RestBolt(), 30000);
```

Now, given this API, my guess is that Storm would have no other choice other than starting 30k threads and that would be potentially bad. I see in the source code that Storm uses Netty, I guess it could support this operation more efficiently by using Storm calls... If fictitious beautiful Netty, Storm and Java API existed, this would look something like this:

```
public static class RestBolt implements IRichBolt {
    ...
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        Future<String> classes = (new AsyncPost('http://my.classifier.com', data = tuple.getString(0)));
        _collector.emit(tuple, new FutureValues(classes));
        _collector.ack(tuple);
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to use asynchronous calls to have massive scalability with very few threads in Storm?